# DRF file.read() contains HTML header info and not just file content

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm not sure where the problem is, but file.read() should only give me file content. I'm printing out the first 200 chars and get content headers instead of just the uploaded file data.

Uploader

```
local_file = os.path.join(basedir, 'a.jpg')
url = baseurl + 'a.jpg'
files = {'file': open(local_file, 'rb')}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token sometoken'}
r = requests.put(url, files=files, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

View

```
class FileUploadView(BaseAPIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        data = file_obj.read()
        print(data[:200])
        return Response(status=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And the output printed is:

b'--139822073d614ac7935850dc6d9d06cd\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.jpg"\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xe1!(Exif\x00\x00II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\t\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00x\x03\x00\x00\x01\x01\t\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x0f\x01\x02\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00HTC\x00\x10\x01\x02\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x00\x00'

How come I see all this extra data and not just the file content? Dis has been driving me bonkers and is probably going to be something simple.

Comment: am not totally sure, but maybe try maybe try either switching to a `POST` or explicitly setting the content type to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Thanks @Cory. I got it working, but I'm going to switch to multipart. seems like the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

With FileUploadParser you need to send the file content with data

```
with open(local_file, 'rb') as fh:
    r = requests.put(url, data=fh, headers=headers, verify=False)
```